# Best practice for collecting a response from a third party

Tags: plugin-development

So I'm in the middle of creating a plugin that allows users to make payments with GoCardless. Once payment has been made on the GoCardless website the user needs to be redirected to a PHP script that will confirm the payment was all hunkie-dorie... but....

Where do I put this script? At the moment I've put it inside a folder that is inside the htdocs folder but I'm having problems calling `craft()->plugin_name->confirmPayment()` from this location as `craft()` is undefined here.

Help greatly appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After the payment has been made, you can have the response callback go to an [anonymous](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/plugins/controllers#allowing-anonymous-access-to-actions) [action method](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/plugins/controllers#linking-directly-to-controller-actions) on your [plugin's](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/plugins/introduction) [controller](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/plugins/controllers).

The URL for that would look something like this:

```
http://mydomain.com/index.php/actions/myPluginHanlde/myPluginController/myPluginAction
```

From there you can perform any additional business logic (validation, record saving, etc.), and `$this->redirect('');` to a success template.

Comment: Thanks for your help! Can I? GoCardless wants me to provide a url for the user to be sent to after submitting their payment details. So I've provided my url that is: http://www.<the-site>.co.uk/api/gocardless/payment-made/index.php How can I call the action from within that? Or am I looking at it wrong?

Comment: Updated answer.

Comment: That looks brilliant, I'll try it ASAP. Thank you so much!

Comment: Worked a treat, nice one!